# Writing a regex for matching special types of folder path

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a Regular Expression to find all of folder paths except the ones that are child to specific parents. For example, consider my string contains one of the following items and I want to match the whole string if the path is not a child of folder1 and folder3:

```
string 1: "/folder1/subfolder_0"
string 2: "/folder1/"
string 3: "/folder1"
string 4: "/folder2/subfolder_0"
string 5: "/folder3/subfolder_0"
string 6: "/folder3"
```

I use the regex /`^\/((?!(folder1|folder3)\/)([\w\/])+)$/` to achieve my matching. But it matches string(s) 3 and 6 too while I want to match only the 4th string. My problem is where the string ends with folder1 and folder3 following no / character. Is it possible with regex?

Comment: Please format your question. There's an help available in the toolbar

Comment: Sorry, @Denys. The question is edited now.

Comment: Try [`/^(?!\/folder[13](?:\/|$))[\w\/]+$/`](https://regex101.com/r/xO8cU2/1), or maybe just [`/^(?!\/folder[13](?:\/|$))/`](https://regex101.com/r/xO8cU2/2)

Comment: Great! Thank you @Wiktor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `^/((?!(folder1|folder3)/)([\w/])+)$` regex matches `"/folder1"` and `"/folder3"` because you only fail the string match if the `folder1` or `folder3` are followed with `/`.  You need  to allow the end of string, replace that second `/` in the lookahead with `(?:/|$)`.

You may use

```
/^\/(?!folder[13](?:\/|$))[\w\/]+$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xO8cU2/3)

*Note* that `[\w\/]+$` might be redundant here if you need to just `RegExp#test()` these values.

Comment: OK, I knew where the problem arise, but I did not know how to resolve it. You helped me a lot. Thanks again.